# TypeError: Cannot read property 'combine' of undefined in rollup bundle [monorepo] [yarn workspaces] [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, typescript, rollupjs, monorepo

I'm trying to create a bundle of a nodeJS app within a yarn monorepo.

Compiling Typescript to JS works fine (through tsc), then rollup finishes too. However, when running the compiled bundle in node, I'm getting the following exception that points to that the external module cannot be found:

```
/Users/benedikt/code/rollup-test/services/nodejs-service-1/dist/rollup/packages/service-utils/lib/logging.js:40
            format: winston_1.format.combine(winston_1.format.colorize(), winston_1.format.simple()),
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'combine' of undefined
```

In my rollup.config.js, I'm making all node_modules packages external so they don't get transpiled by the rollup.

The configurations are below and [a project that reproduces the issue is available here](https://github.com/bhr/rollup-test).

**UPDATE** I've created another sample project with even smaller scope that reproduces the issue [on replit](https://replit.com/@bhr1/rollup-plugin-repro).

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const defaultExternal = (id) => {
  return (
    !id.startsWith('@vestico') &&
    !id.startsWith(`\0`) &&
    !id.startsWith(`~`) &&
    !id.startsWith(`.`) &&
    !id.startsWith(process.platform === `win32` ? process.cwd() : `/`)
  );
};

export default {
  input: './dist/server/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: './dist/rollup',
    format: 'cjs',
    preserveModules: true,
  },
  external: defaultExternal,
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      rootDir: '../../',
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.node', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
    }),
    commonjs({ sourceMap: !isProduction }),
    json(),
  ],
};
```

**Logging.ts**

```
import { LoggingWinston } from '@google-cloud/logging-winston';
import { transports as wtransports, format, createLogger } from 'winston';

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.COLD_START_TEST !== 'true';
const transports = isProduction
  ? [
      new LoggingWinston({
        resource: {
          type: 'cloud_run_revision',
          labels: {
            configuration_name: process.env.K_CONFIGURATION!,
            location: process.env.K_LOCATION!,
            revision_name: process.env.K_REVISION!,
            service_name: process.env.K_SERVICE!,
          },
        },
        serviceContext: {
          service: process.env.K_SERVICE!,
          version: process.env.K_REVISION!,
        },
      }),
    ]
  : [
      new wtransports.Console({
        level: 'debug',
        format: format.combine(format.colorize(), format.simple()),
      }),
    ];

export const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  transports,
});
```

**Logging.ts (compiled by tsc + transpiled by rollup**

```
'use strict';

var logging = require('../../../_virtual/logging.js_commonjs-exports');
var require$$0 = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');
var require$$1 = require('winston');

function _interopDefaultLegacy (e) { return e && typeof e === 'object' && 'default' in e ? e : { 'default': e }; }

var require$$0__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(require$$0);
var require$$1__default = /*#__PURE__*/_interopDefaultLegacy(require$$1);

(function (exports) {
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.initLogging = exports.logger = void 0;
/* eslint-disable prefer-spread */
const logging_winston_1 = require$$0__default["default"];
const winston_1 = require$$1__default["default"];
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.COLD_START_TEST !== 'true';
const transports = isProduction
    ? [
        new logging_winston_1.LoggingWinston({
            resource: {
                type: 'cloud_run_revision',
                labels: {
                    configuration_name: process.env.K_CONFIGURATION,
                    location: process.env.K_LOCATION,
                    revision_name: process.env.K_REVISION,
                    service_name: process.env.K_SERVICE,
                },
            },
            serviceContext: {
                service: process.env.K_SERVICE,
                version: process.env.K_REVISION,
            },
        }),
    ]
    : [
        new winston_1.transports.Console({
            level: 'debug',
            format: winston_1.format.combine(winston_1.format.colorize(), winston_1.format.simple()),
        }),
    ];
exports.logger = winston_1.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    transports,
});

}(logging.__exports));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@vestico/node-service-1",
  "description": "vestico node service 1",
  "author": "Benedikt",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "server/index",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:run": "tsc --build ./tsconfig.json && nodemon --watch ./ --watch ../../packages src/server/index.ts",
    "dev": "PORT=3011 yarn run dev:run",
    "dev:prod": "PORT=3311 yarn run dev:run",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=production tsc --build ./tsconfig.json && rollup -c",
    "build:prod": "yarn run clean && yarn run compile",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production COLD_START_TEST=true node -r require-so-slow dist/services/widget-api/src/server/index.js",
    "test": "yarn run clean && NODE_ENV=production tsc --build ./tsconfig.jest.json && jest --env=node test --watch",
    "dev:cold-start": "yarn build:prod && NODE_ENV=production COLD_START_TEST=true node dist/rollup/services/nodejs-service-1/dist/server/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/error-reporting": "^2.0.1",
    "@vestico/service-utils": "^1.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gaxios": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nighttrax/eslint-config-tsx": "^6.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.169",
    "@types/lru-cache": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.12",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "rollup": "^2.60.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `tsconfig.json` must use `"module": "esnext"`. Otherwise the compiled code is not compatible.